# CSS rotated element at bottom without height and width

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have a problem with absolute positioning an element with transform: rotate() css.
I have read other posts on SO with similar problem and I used some solutions but still not solve my problem. I tried transform-origin etc.

I want to place my rotated link at the any X position: left, center, right & Y: bottom of a header. I need solution where I don't know width, height of element (different texts).

I think I have a 90% of solution but problem is my link is not placed whre I want. The X position changes with lenght of text.

I have a working code below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>    
  <meta charset="utf-8">    
  <style>
  body {
    background: #333333;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .header-content {
    background: #cccccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 712px;
    margin: 0 auto;   
    padding: 0 45px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
  }
  
  .link-decor {
    border-top: 2px solid #ed217c;
    color: #ffffff;   
    font-size: 14px;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    padding-left: 30px;   
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(50%, -100%);  
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="header-content">
    <div>
      <h1>LOREM<br>IPSUM</h1>
      <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tristique sapien eget magna rutrum, ac fringilla diam elementum. </p>
      <a href="#">learn more</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="link-decor">webpageeeeeee<br>scrollersbarrrrrrrrssssssssssssssss</a>
  </div>        
  
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your HTML to be like this :

```
<div class="header-content">
<div class="in-header"> <!-- add class in-header here -->
  <h1>LOREM<br>IPSUM</h1>
  <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tristique sapien eget magna rutrum, ac fringilla diam elementum. </p>
  <a href="#">learn more</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-decor">webpageeeeeee<br>scrollersbarrrrrrrrssssssssssssssss</a>
</div>
```

I added class to the first child of the `div.header-content` and put the element that you want to rotate inside this div not outside it as you was doing.

Then, I changed the style for the .link-decor to be

```
.link-decor {
    border-top: 2px solid #ed217c;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

and added position relative to the new class `.in-header`

```css
body {
    background: #333333;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .header-content {
    background: #cccccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 712px;
    margin: 0 auto;   
    padding: 0 45px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
  }
  .in-header{
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .link-decor {
    border-top: 2px solid #ed217c;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>    
  <meta charset="utf-8">    
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="in-header">
      <h1>LOREM<br>IPSUM</h1>
      <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tristique sapien eget magna rutrum, ac fringilla diam elementum. </p>
      <a href="#">learn more</a>
      <a href="#" class="link-decor">webpageeeeeee<br>scrollersbarrrrrrrrssssssssssssssss</a>
    </div>
  </div>        
  
</body>
</html>
```